# How to monitor all keystroke actions on Android and iOS like Windows Keylogger?

Tags: android, c++, ios, keylogger

How to monitor all keystrokes on Android OS(without root) and iOS(without jailbreak) just like this kind of [Windows keylogger](https://isafesoft.com/keylogger-pro)?

I already master C++11 programing language?
My question is is it achievable to develop such kind of keylogger on Android OS?
Any tech sample or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have not done so already, hire an attorney. Quickly.

Comment: Generally questions that ask about both Android and iOS are a bad idea since the two platforms are very different and many people have experience in only one; it is typically difficult to answer such questions. You may be better off asking two separate questions, one for each platform.  However, the answer, as you can see below, for iOS is definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't on iOS. That's a security feature.

Comment: But as you can see, there are a whole lot of such anroid keyloggers in marketing. http://keyloggers.mobi/best-android-keylogger/

Comment: iOS is more secure in that regard.